# Genetic Algorithm, Population initialisation

Tags: c, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

I'm trying to find a solution to this problem of initializing a timetable, the `days[][]` of each `oldpop` has to be printed for successfully generating new timetables.

Each position in days must consist of a number in which the **10's place** shows the **room number**, and **one's place** shows the **subject number**. The room number array consists of each hour the room is available or free, any hour and day combination tells us if the room is **free** ie, =**0** or **occupied** =**1**. Similarly, the subjects array tells us how many times each subject must be taught per week.

There are a lot of unused variables in this code, please ignore them as I will implement them later on. I also would like to apologize for the extremely wrong indentation. Time restricts me to rectify that as of now.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include <time.h>


#define MAXP 10 //population size (best if chosen between 10-15)

struct pop{
    int days[5][9];
    int faculty;
    int students;
    int subjects[6];
    int labs[2];
    int rooms[9][5][9];
    int labaratory[9][2];
    int obj;
} old_pop[MAXP],benchmark;

int random_number_creator(int upper, int lower)
{
    int n;
    n = rand() % (upper-lower)+ lower;
    return n;
}
void initialize_days(struct pop b)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<9;j++)
         if(j!=5)
          b.days[i][j]=0;
         else
          b.days[i][j]=11111;
    }
}
void initialize_benchmark(struct pop b)
{
    int i,j,k;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<9;j++)
         if(j!=5)
          b.days[i][j]=0;
         else
          b.days[i][j]=11111;
    }
    b.faculty=9;
    b.students=100;
    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    {   
       if(i<4)
        b.subjects[i]=3;
       else 
        b.subjects[i]=2;
    }    
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        b.labs[i]=3;
    }
    for(i=0;i<9;i++)
    {   
     for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        for(k=0;k<9;k++)
            if(i!=5)
                 b.rooms[i][j][k]=0;

    }
    for(i=6;i<9;i++)
    {   
      for(j=0;j<8;j++)
        b.labaratory[i][j]=0;
    }
}
int check_avail_days(struct pop p, int b)
{   
    int j,count=0;
    for(j=0;j<9;j++)
    {  
       if(p.days[b][j]==0)
         count+=1;

    }
    return (count);
}
int check_avail_hours(struct pop b,int d)
{
    int i,count=0;
    for(i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
        if(b.days[d][i]==0)
          count+=1;
    }
    return count;

}

int hours_alloter(struct pop b,int d)
{
    int i,j=0;
    int arr[9]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    for(i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
        if(b.days[d][i]==0)
        {   
            arr[j]=i;
            j++;
        }

    }
    int n;
    n=random_number_creator(j,0);
    return arr[n];
}
int availble_room(struct pop b,int s, int r, int q)
{   
    if(b.rooms[s][r][q]==0)
     return 1;
    else
     return 0;
}
void initpop()
{
  int i,j,count=0, a=0;

  for(i=0;i<MAXP;i++)
    old_pop[i].obj=0;

  for(i=0;i<MAXP;i++)
    {
     initialize_benchmark(benchmark);
     initialize_days(old_pop[i]);
     do{
        printf("\nloop 1 entery\n");

        int subject1,ss,fa=benchmark.faculty,h1;
 for(subject1=random_number_creator(6,0);benchmark.subjects[subject1]>=0;benchmark.subjects[subject1]--)
    {
       printf("\nloop 2 entery\n");
       int cou=1,r;
       ss=subject1*10;
       while(cou!=0&&benchmark.subjects[subject1]!=0&&fa!=0)
       {  
          printf("\nloop 3 entery\n");
          int d=random_number_creator(6,0),hi;
          cou=check_avail_hours(benchmark,d);
          hi=hours_alloter(benchmark,d);
          old_pop[i].days[d][h1]=ss;
          do
            {   
                printf("\nloop 4 entery\n");
                r=random_number_creator(9,0);
                if(availble_room(benchmark,r,d,hi)==1)
                {
                   benchmark.rooms[r][d][hi]=1;
                   old_pop[i].days[d][hi]+=r;
                   benchmark.faculty-=1;
                   fa++;
                   a++;
                }
                else
                    continue;
            }while(a==0);
        }
        old_pop[i].faculty=fa;  
    }

    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        count+=benchmark.subjects[i];
    }
}while(count!=0);
  }
}

int main()
{
    initpop();
    int i,j,k;
    for(i=0;i<MAXP;i++)
    {   
       printf("\nPop %d\n",i);
       for(j=0;j<5;j++)
       {   printf("\n");
           for(k=0;k<9;k++)
           printf("   %d",old_pop[i].days[j][k]);
       }
     }
   return 0;
 }
```

### Current Issue

The code gets stuck in an infinite loop, preventing me from understanding the logical error.

### Expected Result

10 timetables each randomly generated, each position specifying the room number in the 10's place, and subject number in the 1's place. ie, 52 implies 5th room and 2nd subject

Comment: Always try to provide a minimal, reproducible code as an example. Writing a better question increases the likelihood of getting a solution. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Similar to [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56855232/my-c-code-for-a-genetic-algortihtm-is-not-functioning-it-dosent-enter-into-the).

Comment: I see you have `else continue;` immediately before `} while(...);` so that `continue` is redundant. Did you intend the `continue` to apply to an outer loop?

Answer (score 0):

The primary error is that you overlooked that `struct` arguments to functions are passed by value, i. e.

```
     initialize_benchmark(benchmark);
     initialize_days(old_pop[i]);
```

pass copies of `benchmark` and `old_pop[i]` to the `initialize_…` functions, where only those copies are filled with the desired values (and discarded on function return), while the global `benchmark` and `old_pop[]` remain zeroed. We have to change those calls to

```
     initialize_benchmark(&benchmark);
     initialize_days(&old_pop[i]);
```

as well as the function parameter type to a pointer

```
void initialize_days(struct pop *b)
void initialize_benchmark(struct pop *b)
```

and every occurrence of `b.` in those functions to `b->`. After that, you can continue to debug the program.